# Ubuntu Boot-Repair stuck at "applying changes"

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot, grub, uefi, zorin

Windows 11 updated and it break the booting process of Ubuntu (Zorin OS 16.3). So now after booting I get: Unexpected return from initial read: Volume Corrupt. buffer size 1000. Failed to load image.

So I tried Boot-Repair tool from a live USB but it gets stuck at "Applying changes".

I was suggested to disable "*Secure Boot*", and even "*TPM 2.0*" but it didn't fix the booting. I was wondering if anyone has been able to repair it without reinstalling the OS. Here is [my log](https://sprunge.us/mcUf4l) from the Boot-Repair tool. I would appreciate any suggestions to fix this, thanks in advance.

Comment: Boot Repair is ONLY for reinstalling Grub, something the very likely you didn't have to do. What was the problem originally? Was it booting directly to Windows? That *should* be expected with any Windows feature update but ALL it takes is changing the boot order back to the Linux you have in UEFI settings > Boot (and your own log ends with *Please do not forget to make your UEFI firmware boot on the Zorin...*). when does the error message appear?

Comment: And, as always, when dual-booting, the Windows' Fast Startup "feature" must be disabled and, if already disabled, confirm it still is after such Windows updates and act accordingly. Does your Windows boot fine?